# I have two table called Event table and Date table.I want to show following display table without duplicating rows using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, oracle10g, date-format

```
ASSENDING_ORDERD_DISPLAY_TABLE(ACCORDING TO START DATE )

EVENT_NAME      START_DATE                  FROM_TO 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FASHION SHOW    2013/07/09 08:00:00 a.m.    2013/07/09 08:00:00 a.m.- 2013/07/16 05:00:00 p.m.
STAGE  DRAMA    2013/07/10 08:00:00 a.m.    2013/07/10 08:00:00 a.m.- 2013/07/15 04:00:00 p.m.
FILM_FESTIVAL   2013/07/11 08:00:00 a.m.    2013/07/11 08:00:00 a.m.- 2013/07/12 04:00:00 p.m.
```

In above display table I want to display event name,start date and From-to which are>=SYSDATE. Event table I use E_ID as primary key and Date table also I use E_ID. There date table does not use any primary key. Because dates are repeated.I know how to display using java vector and other stuff. But I don't know how to code sql.

[image: Link]

Comment: SELECT blah,etc FROM event Join Date ON event.e_id=date.e_id

Comment: But how to get minimum date of start date and maximum date of end date? When I'm coding MIN(start_date) and MAX(end_date) this is outed maximum and minimum dates of whole date table.

Comment: SELECT m.E_ID,m.E_NAME,m.E_VENUE,TO_CHAR(MIN(d.D_START_DATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')min_st_dt,TO_CHAR(MAX(d.D_END_DATE),'DD-MM-YYYY')max_en_date FROM EVENT m,DATE d where m.E_ID=d.E_ID GROUP BY d.E_ID ORDER BY min_st_dt

Comment: INTO TO_CHAR format, time format also added.Above code doesn't out expected output.

Comment: Is this mysql or Oracle?

Comment: Oracle.I think there is not big difference both two. I'm not much expert with sql.

Comment: You have to specify what you want,that query does its job.You want min date from where,as it is the only condition in that set is m.id=d.id so it selects all rows where that condition is satisfied.You have to narrow it down.Be more clear in what you want,post the results of the join adn the expected results.Edit your main post,dont comment.

Comment: Because of less reputation I'm couldn't post image what I want and very difficult to explain. If you can please send me a mail address.I'm big issue with this. If can please help me.

Comment: Can you post the link now?OR if you cant add it as text.

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/pdftjpl1r/Event.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For **MySQL**

```
SELECT EVENT_NAME, REPLACE(REPLACE(DATE_FORMAT(START_DATE, '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p'), 'AM', 'a.m.'), 'PM', 'p.m.') START_DATE, 
       CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(DATE_FORMAT(START_DATE, '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p'), 'AM', 'a.m.'), 'PM', 'p.m.'), ' - ', 
              REPLACE(REPLACE(DATE_FORMAT(END_DATE, '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p'), 'AM', 'a.m.'), 'PM', 'p.m.')) FROM_TO
FROM (SELECT ET.EVENT_NAME, MIN(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(ET.START_DATE, '.', ''), '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p')) START_DATE, 
             MAX(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(ET.START_DATE, '.', ''), '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p')) END_DATE
      FROM EVENT_TABLE ET INNER JOIN DATE_TABLE DT ON ET.E_ID = DT.E_ID
      GROUP BY ET.E_ID
     ) AS A;
```