# How to display following display table using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g

Link http://s17.postimg.org/pdftjpl1r/Event.png

I have above two table.I want to display third table using oracle. I know display those data using java,vector and other stuff.But couldn't code correct oracle code.In the above display table shows data which are >=SYSDATE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have two table called Event table and Date table.I want to show following display table without duplicating rows using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674443/i-have-two-table-called-event-table-and-date-table-i-want-to-show-following-disp)

Comment: If you want to clarify things or clean up your question, you should edit the existing question rather than adding a new one.

Comment: But previous I didn't got correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is something like this:

```
select e.event_name,
       min(dt.start_date) as start_date,
       min(dt.start_date)||'-'||max(dt.end_date) as FromTo
from event e join
     date_table dt
     on e.e_id = dt.e_id
group by e.event_name;
```

You may need use `to_char()` to convert date/times to the right format.  You don't specify wht the types are in the data, so it is hard to say what needs conversion.

Comment: Is this "min(dt.start_date) as start_date" give write value? Because previously I used MIN(START_DATE) which gives me minimum start date of whole date table.

Comment: You need to use `min(start_date)` with `group by`.  It gives you the earliest start date for each event.

Comment: I have another problem.I want to upcoming events.I got MAX(dt.end_date)>=sysdate. But When I display start date which is minimum date of start date. But that day may be past date.Example event happen today,tomorrow and day after tomorrow.Today I display start date as "today"(minimum start date). But when tomorrow come I showed start date as previous date. Because minimum start date is yesterday. How should I change my code?

Comment: How should I change above code?